# How to load Forms from Dll in less time,

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-assembly

Hi there I have forms in diffrent project but in same Solution which is a dll project,,, I want to open (show) forms on button click event in another project,, I m doing this without any problem,, But it takes little time to open,,, I want that i could make these forms or dll files on Standby mode,, i mean if i call them,,, they open quickly ,,

I m using this code:

```
Imports Transactions 'Transaction is my projects name from which I want to call forms
```

In Button Click Event

```
Dim FrmDrVouchers As Transaction.FrmDebitVouchers = New Transactions.FrmDebitVouchers()

FrmDrVouchers.Show()
```

Thanks

Comment: How many controls do you have in your forms? This is one of the most common causes of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the first line of your button click event somewhere outside the Click event (e.g. in the constructor) and make FrmDrVoucers a member of your class, such that the form simply needs to be shown in response to a click event rather than being constructed first.

Comment: Should i put it in main Forms Load Event,,

Comment: How to make it member of my class,